# Adding a hook to Gunicorn for raven-python (sentry client)

Tags: python, gunicorn, sentry, raven

I want to know where i would put this into either my code or gunicorn's in order to get raven running. http://raven.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config/django.html#gunicorn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bit late but anyway :)

You need to add this into your Gunicorn config file. For example when you spin up `gunicorn_django` you can pass it a `-c` (`--config`) argument which takes a path to python file.

Gunicorn will use this file to load configuration settings not passed as arguments, like workers and log paths etc etc. But you can also include functions gunicorn will call at certain points of the processes life cycle. This is where you would put the raven setup, according to the Raven docs.

For example:

```
$ gunicorn_django -c /path/to/gunicorn_settings.py
```

The file could contain the following:

```
workers = 2
bind = 'unix:/tmp/my_project_name.sock'  # Binds to a unix socket rather than ip/port
errorlog = '/path/to/logs/gunicorn.error.log'

def when_ready(server):
    from django.core.management import call_command
    call_command('validate')
```

Be careful to ensure your `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` is exported correctly otherwise `call_command('validate')` will throw a `SystemExit` and your process will fail to start.

You can read more on Gunicorn config files at: http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/configure.html

Comment: Is this really needed anymore? I know the raven docs recommend adding this hook, but I don't understand why it's necessary. I don't have any issues even though I've not added this hook. There is a github ticket regarding this https://github.com/getsentry/raven-python/issues/286

Comment: call_command('validate') is throwing a SystemExit, how can I export  DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE correclty? @krak3n

Comment: You need to export it as an environment variable. When running Gunicorn try running with this:

gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:8000 --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=path.to.settings

You can also set environment variables in the gunicorn configuration files.

Comment: gunicorn salon.wsgi -c salon/gunicorn.conf.py --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=salon.settings , but is return : "ImportError: Could not import settings 'salon.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named salon.settings"

Comment: I don't know your application setup, its given you hints as to what the problem maybe, your application will need to be on the python path, is it installed correctly etc? Please see this on python packaging: http://www.scotttorborg.com/python-packaging/

Comment: I think the setup is correct, because when I run just "gunicorn salon.wsgi" it works. I'm runinng the command on the same path of the manage.py file of my project and my gunicorn.conf.py file is on the same of the setting.py